# Bootstrap contact form not sending emails (FormTools neither)

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, contacts

I've tried searching high and low for a resolution to get a contact form to send e-mails for a few days now. Currently using Bootstrap. My host allows you to install FormTools but, although the enquirys are visible within FormTools, e-mails still do not arrive.

```html
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
   <label for="exampleInputName">Full name</label>
   <input type="name" name="cf_name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName1" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="Eg. John Smith">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
   <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
   <input type="email" name="cf_email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="example@example.co.uk">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleSelect1">Subject of enquiry</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="cf_subject" id="exampleSelect1">
       <option>CCTV & Security</option>
       <option>Door Access</option>
       <option>Electrical</option>
       <option>Networking</option>
       <option>PC Repairs</option>
       <option>Smart Thermostats</option>
       <option>Other</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleTextarea">Message contents</label>
   <textarea class="form-control" name="cf_message" id="exampleTextarea" rows="3" placeholder="My enquiry..."></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

contact.php:

```html
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_subject = $_POST['cf_subject'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'myemail@live.com';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message .= 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'Subject: '.$field_subject."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly if required.');
  window.location = 'contact.html';
 </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to myemail@live.com');
  window.location = 'contact.html';
 </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

I've not had much experience with PHP and I've tried a few samples of code but I feel like I'm making no progress and although I've tried searching, I'm unsure how to implement certain solutions.

If someone could help or guide me (even point out a mistake I've probably made myself) that would be amazing.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What debugging have you done?  What are the values of `$mail_to`, `$subject`, `$body_message`, and `$headers` right before calling `mail()`?  Are the values what you expect?  What is the value of `$mail_status` after calling `mail()`?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't debugged at all but I am going to now. I'll admit I underestimated how different PHP could be. The above code was copied from an article I found which stated it should just work off the bat. I wasn't sure how to even see where I was going wrong haha.

Comment: I ran your code and it worked just fine. The only things I changed were the email address to send the form info to, and the form's action URL because I ran it on my own server. So either your problem is something as simple as a typo in your email address or your action address, or there's something else with your server's mail settings to consider. Best to check your mail's return status.